# Using Backbone.js depended views, models, views' render funcs, listening to events, from another View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is it possible to use from a view, another view listed as the dependency of the first view, its model, and render function etc., which are however not listed as dependency of the first view, all defined with require.js and Backbone.js?

In my case all the code files are loaded successfully, but I cannot have the second view rendered, first view does not have a template to be rendered, it just decides accordingly to render the login only app view or entrance view to user login and register by checking the value of the lofinModels 'loginp' attribute true or false?  So I am thinking on the possible mistakes I have done. JS console has no errors.

first view looks like so:

```
    define([
  'jquery',
  'ratchet',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',

  'entrance/entranceview',
  'app/appview',
  ],
  function($, Ratchet, _, Backbone, EntranceView, AppView){
      var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({

          el: $('body'),

          initialize: function(){

              this.entranceView = new EntranceView();
              this.entranceView.loginModel.fetch();
              this.listenTo( this.entranceView.loginModel, 'sync', this.render );
              this.appView = new AppView();

              this.render();
          },
          render: function() {
              if ( this.entranceView.loginModel.get('loginp') == true ) {
                  this.appView.render();

                  this.$el.empty();
                  this.$el
                    .append(this.appView.el);
              }
              else {
                  this.entranceView.render();

                  this.$el.empty();               
                  this.$el
                    .append(this.entranceView.el);
              }
          },
      });

      return MainView;
});
```

second view:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    'entrance/loginmodel',
    'entrance/registermodel',

    'text!entrance/logintemplate.html',
    'text!entrance/registertemplate.html',
    ],
    function(_, Backbone, LoginModel, RegisterModel, LoginTemplate, RegisterTemplate){
        var EntranceView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $('body'),
            initialize: function(){
                this.loginModel = new LoginModel();
                this.registerModel = new RegisterModel();

                //this.render();
            },
            render: function() {
                this.$el.empty();
                this.$el.html( this.template_login( this.loginModel.attributes ) );
                return this;
            },

            events: {
                'keydown input' : 'updateform',
                'click #renlogbtn' : 'render_login',
                'click #renregbtn' : 'render_register',
                'click #logbtn' : 'login',
                'click #regbtn' : 'register',
            },

            template_login: _.template( LoginTemplate ),
            template_register: _.template( RegisterTemplate ),

            updateform: function(e){
                var el = e.target;
                var formData = {};
                formData[ el.id ] = $(el).val();
                this.loginModel.set( formData );
                this.registerModel.set( formData );
            },
            render_login: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                this.$el.empty();
                this.$el.html( this.template_login( this.loginModel.attributes ) );
                return this;
            },
            render_register: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                this.$el.empty();
                this.$el.html( this.template_register( this.registerModel.attributes ) );
                return this;
            },
            login: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                //$( el ).val('');
                this.loginModel.save();
                console.log( JSON.stringify( this.loginModel.attributes ) );
            },
            register: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //$( el ).val('');
                this.registerModel.save();
                console.log( JSON.stringify( this.registerModel.attributes ) );

            },
        });

        return EntranceView;
})
```

and one of the model dependencies of the second view is:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    ],
    function(_, Backbone) {
        var LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

            urlRoot: '/login',
            defaults: {
                username: null,
            },

            initialize: function(){
                this.fetch();
            },
        });

        return LoginModel;
});
```

Also I do not use render() in the initialise property of the subviews because when I create them from the parent view they render themselves which I do not want. Since I want to render which view should be rendered. So I should be able to call the subview's render from the parent view, and should be able to listen to events on subviews' models, and fire callbacks of the subviews for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're setting your `sync` event listener after calling fetch it may not be called at all. In addition, if you're accesing the `LoginModel` from main, it may be clearer code to create your instances and add your dependencies on that view.

Moreover, I don't think mixing two different views into one is a smart move. It seems you're saving some lines but the tradeoff is harder code to maintain/modify in the future. I would create different `LoginView` and `RegisterView` with their models. Different functions/responsabilities, different classes.

In addition, a view like this that doesn't render anything for itself look more like a controller, or in Backbone world, a router. You're basically deciding which view to present based on a server query. Supposing this page is served at "/home" (or "#home" with hash urls), extract that logic to your router:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "home": "showHome",
    "login": "showLogin",
    "register": "showRegister"
  },
  showHome: function(){
    var loginModel = new LoginModel();
    loginModel.fetch({
      success: function(model){
        if(model.get("loginp")){
          //show you app view for logged in users!
          var appView = new AppView();
          appView.render();
        }
        else {
           //not logged in!
           Backbone.history.navigate("/login", {trigger:true})
        }
      }
    );
  },
  showLogin: function(){
     //display your login view
  },
  showRegister: function(){
     //display your register view
  }
});
```

Of course your your Login and Entrance views `el` should be "body" if they're full-page views.

This may look like much more code, but keeping the Single Responsibity Principle helps a lot.

Comment: What I have did to fix just before your answer was to change the sub renders' place in the render:
`render: function() {
     if ( this.entranceView.loginModel.get('loginp') == true ) {
      
      this.$el.empty();
      this.$el
     .append(this.appView.$el);
        this.appView.render();
     
     }
       else {
      
      this.$el.empty();      
      this.$el
       .append(this.entranceView.$el);
        this.entranceView.render();
     
     }
    },`
And it works. But I think your comment on routers as controller, and views I should consider.

Comment: Wow I forgot to format as code it was horrible. Trust me - been there: one view, one template, one responsibility. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I didn't understand the var self = this, loginModel= new LoginModel parts. Do you have a typo. Or could you explain in brief.

Comment: Hi no typo, I declared self but didn't use it in the end. You can declare two or more variables with a single `var`. ;) Removed it for clarity.

Comment: I will try this. Now ı have prepared your code as my mainrouter module.

Comment: I think your self declaration is what I do directly as this.loginModel=new LoginModel from inside a backbone object.

Comment: How does routers loaded like single page apps without reloading whole page or asynchronously. I ask before I bake my module and integrate.

Comment: What if I have a homeview that will show three subviews on the screen. The templates of three subviews will render into inside the homeview once visible at a time while home view still has visible things like buttons tabs for to view these views. Should I still listen for click events in homeview for subviews to trigger corresponding methods of homeview and route there via defined mainrouter routes for this job?

Comment: What do you think about that? Or inner views should be used?

Comment: Read about Backbone Layout to handle regions which can load one view at a time. For the routing parte, it depends: you want the URL to be bookmarkable? Then use routing. Otherwise just use events.